ZingChart link style per class (cls)
I'm currently trying to create a tree graph using Zingchart and I can't get links to get their own style per class.
From TFM there's a link[cls-n] option available and I thought it'd be used the same way as the node[cls-n] one.
I defined my link:
    {"type":"link","source":"1:RAH","target":"1:4:RAH","cls":"UH"}

and defined my link format:
    'link[cls-UH]': {
      lineWidth: 2,
      lineColor: 'red',
      lineStyle: 'dashdot'
    },
    link: {
      lineWidth: 3,
      lineColor: 'blue',
      lineStyle: 'solid'
    }

I only get a solid blue line and not a red dashdot one.
I've been searching in ZingChart manual without result.
Searched for sample code but found none.
Looks like my "cls" entry is ignored.

We just noticed there is an issue where adding generic styles for the link i.e. link:{}, after the custom styles will override all the custom styles and we're working around the clock to have this problem resolved.
Otherwise for family nodes, you can add styling properties to an individual link between a target and source/family node by giving it a cls attribute to set a unique class on the link for styling. I've done this to the link connecting to the abraham node and set it's color to green in this demo.


Ha ha nice. I removed the generic "link" and kept all the specific ones and indeed it works.
Up to bug-correction time, every link will have to have its own style then!

@YoannMainguy This bug was fixed in the latest version of ZingChart i.e. v2.9.14. You might want to check it out and give us some feedback.
